# How to prevent regex from converting bbcode hyperlinks?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression which will parse the content of a message and convert plain text hyperlinks into HTML hyperlinks.

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?:https?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+",
                             "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");
```

It is fine when converting http or https hyperlinks.

The problem is that I also have other hyperlinks enclosed within bbcode tags which I do not want the regular expression to converted into HTML hyperlinks.

E.g. `[IMG]http://www.google.com/img.png[/IMG]` or `[YOUTUBE]http://www.youtube.com[/YOUTUBE]`

How do I change my regular expression to prevent the regex from converting bbcode hyperlinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind.

```
"(?<!\])(?:https?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+"
```

The `(?<!\])` will only allow the rest of the URL pattern to match if it does not immediately follow a `']'`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using negative lookahead like this to avoid matching bbcode links:

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?:https?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+(?!.*\\[/)",
                         "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");
```